# How to replace content of a regex Named Capture Group in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a java project and the following regex pattern with named capture groups:

```
(?<department>\w+(-\w)??)\s{1,5}(?<number>\w+(-\w+)?)-(?<section>\w+)\s(?<term>\d+)\s(?<campus>\w{2})
```

I wanted to replace the value of one of the named group with a wild card character (*). All of the replace methods in the Matcher class appear to be tied to replacing a specific regex value. Since the string is not guaranteed to be unique, I want to replace by the group name.

Is there a way to leverage the Matcher class to provide this substitution capability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I can use the start and end methods of the matcher to determine the range of characters that need to be replaced. I can then use a StringBuilder to delete the range and insert the specified replacement value. I wrote the following method to handle this situation.

```
public static String replaceNamedGroup(String source, Pattern pattern, String groupName, String replaceValue) {
  if (source == null || pattern == null) {
    return null;
  }

  Matcher m = pattern.matcher(source);
  if (m.find()) {
    int start = m.start(groupName);
    int end = m.end(groupName);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source);
    sb = sb.delete(start, end);
    if (replaceValue != null) {
      sb = sb.insert(start, replaceValue);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  } else {
    return source;
  }
}
```

Below is some code to show how it is used

```
String str = "ABC 123-123 1234 AB";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<department>\w+(-\w)??)\s{1,5}(?<number>\w+(-\w+)?)-(?<section>\w+)\s(?<term>\d+)\s(?<campus>\w{2})");
String output = replaceNamedGroup(str, pattern, "term", "*");
//outputs Output: ABC 123-123 * AB
System.out.println("Output: " + output);
```

Comment: Instead of [`delete(start, end)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete-int-int-) + [`insert(start, replaceValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert-int-java.lang.String-), the code should use [`replace(start, end, replaceValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace-int-int-java.lang.String-), so the text following the replaced section doesn't need to be moved twice. Use ternary operator to handle the `null`, if needed: `(replaceValue != null ? replaceValue : "")`